# New hard drive: checklist before entering your workflow?

Tags: hard-drive, storage, data-loss-prevention

1, 2... 4+ TiB of data makes a lot of (here choose the appropriate) work/recording/stress/time-to-eg-rebuild-the-array when put on an drive of unknown health.

When getting your hands on a spinning hard drive be it new or not, what points do you check on the hard drive (aka checklist) before you start filling it up with data... or send it back for replacement? By *points* I do mean points (not *tools* which are a matter of possibilities eg. OS, and preference, thanks @Franck Michael for pointing this).

Get the **physical sector size** (for partition alignment, filesystem or raid/lvm setup). eg

```
# fdisk -l /dev/DRIVE
Disk /dev/sdc: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units:                              sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes      «-- physical sector size
I/O size (minimum/optimal):         4096 bytes / 4096 bytes     «--
```

Check S.M.A.R.T. values for possible **defect** ? eg

```
# smartctl -a /dev/DEVICE \
| grep -i 'ID\|reallocated\|pending\|uncorrectable'
```

As any bad value (eg. Val/ue > Worst) for `Reallocated_Sectors`, `offline uncorrectable`, `pending sectors`, and Error log, is bad news and brings the hdd to warranty. [2]

Check **blocks reliability**? if so on whole disk? eg

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=[physical sector size] & pid=$!
kill -USR1 $pidnumer
```

Where the `kill -USR1 $pidnumer` shows how far the zeroing has progressed. `conv` and `noerror` can be added to ensure that every block is tried and upon error (errors are shown in terminal) the zeroing continues [2]

Do you trust S.M.A.R.T. report and if so, which ones? Or do you run additional/other test [3] before you trust the hard drive start using it?

I'd like very much to hear your options.

[2]: Thanks to @DebianJunkie at [Hard drive checking by using dd and md5sum tools](https://superuser.com/questions/798892)
[3]: like *Bonnie++*, *Hitachi Drive Fitness Test*, *HDD Regenerator* which I know very little about.

Comment: To the down voter, please say why. There's hundreds ways to improve a question (or not).

Comment: Is there an actual problem here? It looks like you're just asking how people test an HDD before using it, which is off-topic as it's going to generate a lot of opinion based answers.

Comment: @MichaelFrank you mean there's no way to check a spinning HDD state before putting it in use? Let me clarify my request (hopefully): As no manufacturer nor seller ;) is error prone, when I get a device that I'm *used to* I check a few key points to evaluate its state, especially one I must count on it (e.g. for a bike: tires, chain, platters, brakes... before letting my daughter go to school on it). As for HDDs, better know earlier than latter, ain't it?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that this question isn't a good fit for SuperUser. It's a good question, and would make a good discussion, but not a SU.

Comment: Disks are a major component in many of our daily workflows. We SU should be able to check them for a couple of key points before they enter our workflow or we turn them back to seller. I believe many of us do so. Question to more experienced SU is: **What factual key points to look for** based on your experience? Eg. *S.M.A.R.T. capabilities and attributes value*, *bad block*, or any real-word characteristics.

Comment: Question shortened to which *points* do you test. Reading other answers on SU with @MichaelFrank kind (and a bit vague ;) warning in mind, it appears many come with their *tools* thinking they're the best out there ;)

Comment: This is still opinion based, which is the reason it counts as off-topic.  You should edit your question to be more specific, something that has the same answer every time it's asked (or as close as you can get with people), not 100 different iterations that are slightly different and almost all right (exaggerated of course).  If that makes sense.  I don't have an answer, because my method involves sticking it in the computer and see if it runs okay.  In servers, it's in a raid, so 1 failing isn't going to hurt.

Comment: HDD's health and sector size are no more opinion based than tires' type state or brake, which a SU will always check himself, correct? Even in a Raid rebuilding a multi-TiB array can have a much longer impact than having taken the time to check the drive before eventualy put it in. My own experience is too limited I'm affraid, to know which characteriscs are worth to check before use a HDD knowingly.

Comment: I think this is a fairly good question. Prevention is far better than cure. Given how many questions there are asking "How do I recover data from a broken drive" I think it's perfectly on-topic to ask "How do I minimize my chances of having a drive break" in the first place. Especially when we have quantitative information on certain readings that correlate with earlier failures from large-scale studies.

Answer (score 2):

If I wasn't my reckless self, I might try these things:

Check smart info

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

Run a short smart test

```
smartctl -t short /dev/sda
```

Run conveyance test

```
smartctl -t conveyance /dev/sda
```

Test disk speed

```
hdparm -t /dev/sda
```

Check for kernel messages

```
dmesg
```

Comment: ^_^ and thanks for sharing @RyanBabchishin. Taught me `-t conveyance`.
In your experience does a brand new disk that is checked out of the box, reports trustable SMART attributes values (or better have it powered ON for a moment before)?
And which *attributes* do you read first to quickly check a brand new drive? 
Add a `-l selftest` to read the test results, and if passed, that would very quickly allows that HDD to be used much less blindly.

Comment: I've never received a faulty drive, so I can't say. The only time I've had a smart test fail to detect a problem is once, an SSD was slow and locking up the computer. There were no kernel messages. I ran smartctl -t short and smartctl -a, everything was fine. It turned out the power supply was about to die and was giving choppy/low power to the drive.

Comment: I'm more interested in the results of a self test. I don't understand how to interpret all of the smart values so I have to look them up every time.

Comment: Find the new SSD locks "thanks" to a *dying PSU* share valuable --pesky PSU/transistors issues :/  As for SMART, I start by checking the capabilities (`-c`).
Any SU with some feedback on eg which *SMART attributes* you check first?

Comment: As for BadBlocks: [How many bad sectors do you tolerate in a new hard drive before returning it?](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/3rig71/is_badblocks_e2fsck_still_necessary_with_todays/) and https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/223lrp/e2fsck_badblocks_very_slow/ answer my question and give precious realcase feedbacks.